# Split hastable at key/value pair

Tags: powershell, hash, split, hashtable

How can I split a hashtable starting from a specific key/value pair?

I have  hashtable like the following, just longer:

```
Name               Value
----               -----
Name               Alpha
Age                    2
Position           Trick
Start date      01-01-31
End date         Unknown
Name               Corax
Age                   21
Position           Sneak
Earnings          40'000
End Date         Unknown
Name               Horus
Age                   22
Position            Dead
Why               Heresy
End date        03-30-30
```

I tried `Group-Object` but it failed.

I particularly wanted to separate it by Name and everything aside from Name, Age and Position are not consistent.

My actual issue is that I want to parse the hashtable for the **Name** and **Age** when **Why** = **Heresy**, and unfortunately, the original source of the data is a list of strings, which is the reason why I convert it to a hashtable.

Comment: I might be mistaken but hashtables are intentionally designed to not have a 'position', unlike an array. I think you want to specifically drop the values Name,Age,etc. If there are key names in some of your records where you don't know what those keys are then can you do the opposite and only keep the specific keys you want? `$hashtable | select Name, Age,Position` for example?

Comment: I have updated the my original post, but yeah... I kinda need to get Name and Age when ever `WHY` is `Heresy`... And the ONLY way I can figure out how to get my data parsed like that, is turning into multiple objects or multiple tables from one table

Comment: @A.Zia can you expand on that? What exactly do you want to do with `Name` and `Age` when `Why` `-eq 'Heresy'`?

Comment: So What I need to see is "Who is the Heretic and how old"  and  just use that data for other generic data tasks, like printing it out, search for the Name in another jsonobject and their other data etc

Comment: @A.Zia what's wrong with `if ($hash.Why -eq 'Heresy') { $hash.Name,$hash.Age }`? It's hard to tel how to handle this without knowing how you'll use it, but I'm going to venture a guess that a hashtable is just not the best object for you.

Comment: @briantist the problem is it brings out ALL the Names and not just the one with the `Heresy` ....  you might be correct that maybe hashtables might not be the best, but that was the only option in converting each line of output to string

Comment: @A.Zia in that case it sounds like you have an _array_ of hashtables, not a single one, and you're trying to filter on them. See my edit. It would also help if you showed the code you used to create the original hashtable or array of hashtables.

Comment: According to your sample output your hashtable has multiple keys with the same name. That is not possible. The most prominent features of hashtables is that their keys are unique. Please show how you created the hashtable (more likely a list of hashtables), and also show what you tried with `Group-Object` and how that failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end; I figured something out, Thanks a lot to @briantist for guidance to the right direction.

**My solution code is:**

```
$startobj =  (0..($hastable.count -1)) | where {$hashtable[$_].keys -like "*Name*"}
$endobj = (0..($hashtable.count -1)) | where {$hashtable[$_].keys -like "*End date*"}
$objindex = (0..($hashtable.count -1))
$numberofobjindex = 0..($hashtable.Where({$_.keys -like "*Name*"}).count - 1)


$hashtableparsed = foreach ($numba in $numberofobjindex) {
  $Conv2data = $hashtable[($startobj[$numba]..$endobj[$numba])] 
    [PSCustomObject] @{
    Name = $Conv2data.Name
    Age = $Conv2data.Age
    Why = $Conv2data.Why

          }
   }  

$hashtableparsed
```

I realized that the hashtable data I was presented with had a repeating pattern with `Name` at the start of each cycle, and `End date` at the end.

So I basically did an indexing of the hashtable, and marked and indexed all instances where the cycle would start and end.

I then counted the cycles, and FOR EACH cycle captured the data of hashtable data in the lines particularly of that cycle and turned it into a `PSCustomObject`

Answer (score 5):

Hashtables are not ordered, so you can't rely on a concept of "before" and "after". If you know the specific names of one complete set of keys, then you can loop through the hashtable and build two new ones, so if you wanted one hashtable to contain the Name, Age, and Position, and the other to contain everything else, you can do something like this:

```
$New1 = @{}
$New2 = @{}

$KeysGroup1 = @('Name','Age','Position') # This could just be one value

$MyHashTable.GetEnumerator().ForEach({
    if ($_.Key -in $KeysGroup1) {
        $New1[$_.Key] = $_.Value
    } else {
        $New2[$_.Key] = $_.Value
    }
})
```

You can use an ordered dictionary if order is important for you. You can use a shortcut to create a literal ordered dictionary by preceding a literal hashtable with the `[ordered]` type accelerator:

```
$myOrdered = [ordered]@{ a = 1; z = 5; g = 2 }
```

From there you could do a similar approach to above that relies on order.

To create an ordered dictionary that isn't based on a literal:

```
$myOrdered = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary

# or in PowerShell v5

$myOrdered = [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]::new()

$myOrdered.Add('key','value')
```

---

#### Edit based on comments

It sounds more like what you have is *an array* of hashtables and you now want to go about filtering these.

A `[hashtable]` can (and is often) used as a sort of proto-object, and it can be very useful for that because it often supports the same syntax, and it has built-in literal support.

But you're starting to run into their limits, and at this point I think you want to be dealing with an array of objects and not an array of hashtables.

Luckily, there are really easy ways to create objects in PowerShell right from a hashtable:

```
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $myHash
$obj = [PSCustomObject]$myHash

$objArray = $myHashArray.ForEach({[PSCustomObject]$myHash})
```

Once you've got your array of *objects*, the real fun begins:

```
$heretics = $objArray.Where({$_.Why -eq 'Heresy'})
```

You'll notice I didn't even bother filtering out the other properties here. You shouldn't, until you really need to. Then you can use `Select-Object` or just access the properties you need. So for display purposes you might just do:

```
$heretics | Format-Table Name,Age
```

There's more stuff you can do with an object that you can't with hashtables, like add special types of properties:

```
$objArray | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name IsHeretic -Value { $this.Why -eq 'Heresy' } -Force

$heretics = $objArray.Where({$_.IsHeretic})
```